# Rename default context menu title on right click in webview for cocoa [Objective C]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, contextmenu

I need to open a link in new tab in webview. But on right clik, the context menu is showing `Open Link In New Window` with other menus but no `Open Link In New Tab`. And on clicking `Open Link In New Window`, it'll open in new tab (I enabled tabbing mode on). But I am **unable to change the title** from `Open Link In New Window` to `Open Link In New Tab` and **if I change the title, it won't work**. I couldn't find the solution yet. I am using webView, not WKWebView.

**If my question is duplicate, please refer me to original.**

**Objective C please..**

Edit: My code

```
-(NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
{
    NSMutableArray *modifiedMenuItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    modifiedMenuItems=[defaultMenuItems mutableCopy];
    NSMenuItem *mItem=[[NSMenuItem alloc]init];
    int i=0;
    while(i<[modifiedMenuItems count])
    {
        mItem=[modifiedMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];
        if([mItem tag]==WebMenuItemTagOpenLinkInNewWindow)
        {
            [mItem setTitle:@"Open Link in New Tab"];
            [modifiedMenuItems replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mItem];
            //Here I renamed the title and replaced. But it doesn't works.
            //It is showing like a disabled one.
            //So I added the next line code prior to replacement.
            [mItem setEnabled:YES];
        }
    }
    return modifiedMenuItems;
}
```

Comment: How and when do you change the title? Post your code please.

Comment: @Willeke Included my code.

Comment: What is `[mItem replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mItem]` supposed to do?

Comment: Replace the context menu title Open In New Window with Open In New Tab

Comment: Is this real code? Did you test it?

Comment: Yes it is real. I tested it. We can see the changed title but won't work like "New Window" works. I mean, it will not open nothing.

Comment: I get build error "no visible @interface for 'NSMenuItem' declares the selector 'replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:'" on `[mItem replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mItem];`. If I remove this statement then my app hangs in an infinite loop because `i` isn't incremented.

Comment: @Willeke Sorry, that was my mistake in typing my code here. its not `[mItem replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mItem];` its `[defaultMenuItems replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mItem];`.

Comment: No it isn't, `defaultMenuItems` is a `NSArray`. "error: no visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:'" Replacing an object in an array with the same object doesn't make sense. Just change the title of the menu item.

Comment: @Willeke I used another array too. I'll include in code that too.

Comment: Oh its all about the return type. I'v got it worked after I converted type to NSArray. What an idiot I am..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[modifiedMenuItems replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mItem]` replaces `mItem` with `mItem`. `(NSArray *)modifiedMenuItems` does nothing at runtime. Find the item and set the title:

```
-(NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
{
    for (NSMenuItem *mItem in defaultMenuItems)
    {
        if ([mItem tag] == WebMenuItemTagOpenLinkInNewWindow)
        {
            [mItem setTitle:@"Open Link in New Tab"];
            break;
        }
    }
    return defaultMenuItems;
}
```

That's all. The other issues are not caused by renaming the item.

Answer (score 0):

It was all about the type of return type in my case. I just changed the returning array to `NSArray` from `NSMutableArray`. I'll include the corrected code.

```
-(NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
{
    //Here I need to rename the title of default menu from
    //"Open Link In New Window" to "Open Link In New Tab".
    NSMutableArray *modifiedMenuItems=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    modifiedMenuItems=[defaultMenuItems mutableCopy];
    NSMenuItem *mItem=[[NSMenuItem alloc]init];
    int i=0;
    while(i<[modifiedMenuItems count])
    {
        mItem=[modifiedMenuItems objectAtIndex:i];
        if([mItem tag]==WebMenuItemTagOpenLinkInNewWindow)
        {
            [mItem setTitle:@"Open Link in New Tab"];
            [modifiedMenuItems replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:mItem];
            //Here I renamed the title and replaced. But it doesn't works.
            //It is showing like a disabled one.
            //So I added the next line code prior to replacement.
            [mItem setEnabled:YES];
        }    
        i++;
    }
    //For adding new menu item.
    //[mItem setTitle:@"Your Title"];
    //[mItem setTarget:self];
    //[mItem setAction:@selector(yourActionMethod)];
    //[mItem setTag:/*your desired enum tag value*/];
    //[mItem setEnabled:YES];
    //Then add or insert to any position you want in the modifiedMenuItems array.
    return (NSArray *)modifiedMenuItems;  //Changed the type.
}
```

[image: My_Code]